# connect multiple devices securely to a single device over internet without any static IP

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, hub, iot

I'm an electronics engineer with no experience and knowledge in networking. I'm working on some home automation project and will choose the best way to connect my phone(s) to the HUB(which controls home devices) over internet. The HUB is connected to the ADSL internet with dynamic IP and also contains a GSM module to get control commands with SMS.

The best practical way that I think(with my very very little knowledge) is to connect the HUB to a static IP and then connect the phone application to the HUB using that specific IP. the question is that:

assuming that I can not change my dynamic IP ADSL service to a static one, is there another way to connect multiple devices (or at least one device) to a single hub over the internet in a secure way?

As I said, the HUB contains a GSM module and could inform the client if the IP has been changed over the time(if it helps)

The HUB runs Android and coud be changed to Ubuntu or Windows 10 IoT(If necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a device called HUB that is installed in your home, and is both directly connected to the internet via ADSL (in other words, it's not connected to your home router), and additionally has a GSM module, so it's also connected to the internet via the mobile network.

You want to reach this HUB from anywhere with your phones, and you want to reach it via internet, not via GSM.

So the question is how the phones get the current public internet address of your HUB. The options are:

- Give the HUB a static IPv4 address (ruled out, because your ISP doesn't allow it).
- Give the HUB a static IPv6 address
- Use a *dynamic DNS* service: Assign a name like `hub.milad.dyndns.org` to the current IPv4 address of your hub that is updated when your public IPv4 address changes. There are many such services, google.
- Send all your phones a SMS whenever the public IPv4 changes. This will probably mean x SMS per day, where x is the number of your phones.
- Have your phone query the HUB via SMS whenever it wants to contact it. That will mean 2 SMS per contact attempt.

You can make the SMS secure by adding a cryptographic hash based on some shared secret between the HUB and your application. The DynDNS is secure by requiring a password.

None of them prevents a attacker from guessing or scanning the IPv4 of your HUB, so you should also make communication to the HUB secure by at least requiring a similar cryptographic hash.

Cryptographic libraries exists for that, google.

Comment: This is exactly what i mean and I've got what i exactly wanted from your answer. Thanks a lot